# How to generate again a KeyPair or Key objects from encoded arrays?

Tags: java, encryption

I'm new using the java.security.*

I created a key pair using this code:

```
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");

generator.initialize(256, random);
KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
byte[] public = pair.getPublic().getEncoded();
byte[] private = pair.getPrivate().getEncoded();
```

Now, how can I create the KeyPair object again using only the encoded arrays? Is that possible? I'm realize that would be something like:

```
public KeyPair getKeyPairFromEncoded(byte[] public, byte[] private) {
    KeyPair result = new KeyPair(null, null); 
    result.setPublicFromEncoded(public);
    result.setPrivateFromEncoded(private);
    return result;
}
```

Another solution would be able to get Key objects if this could possible:

```
public Key getKeyFromEncoded(byte[] encoded) {
    Key result = new Key(); //<== I know... This is not possible
    result.setKeyFromEncoded(encoded);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `byte[] public byte[] private` I'm afraid you can't do this.

Comment: @Narmer And create a Key object from an encoded array?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thank you. I'm going to review the solution in that question...

Comment: Yes, the solution was there.